# pandas - groupby a column, apply a function to create a new column - giving incorrect results

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data that looks like this:

```
   Thing   quarter    num_col1    num_col2
    aaa    2010Q1      1.3         99.76
    bbb    2010Q1      11.3        109.76
    ccc    2010Q1      91.3        119.76
   .....
   .....
    aaa    2019Q4      21.3        119.76
    bbb    2019Q4      41.3        299.76
    ccc    2019Q4      201.3       199.76
```

I need to group by `Thing` column, and calculate moving-average for columns `num_col1` and `num_col2` for all the quarters.

Here's what I have tried till now:

```
## define moving-average function
N = 2
def pandas_rolling(x):
    return pd.Series.rolling(x, window=N).mean()

## now group-by and calculate moving averages
things_groupby = df.groupby(by=['Thing'])
## below lines are giving incorrect values
df.loc[:,'num_col1_SMA'] = (things_groupby['num_col1'].apply(pandas_rolling)).values
df.loc[:,'num_col2_SMA'] = (things_groupby['num_col2'].apply(pandas_rolling)).values
```

But, when I do for one of the unique thing from `Thing` column manually like shown below, it gives expected results.

```
pandas_rolling(df.loc[df.loc[:,'Topic']=='aaa'].loc[:,'num_col1']).values
```

what am I doing wrong with calculating the moving-average for individual group and then populating them in the dataframe? How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `values`:

```
df['num_col1_SMA'] = things_groupby['num_col1'].apply(pandas_rolling)
df['num_col2_SMA'] = things_groupby['num_col2'].apply(pandas_rolling)
```

Or:

```
df[['num_col1_SMA', 'num_col2_SMA']] = (things_groupby[['num_col1','num_col2']]
                                               .apply(pandas_rolling))
```

If possible without `groupby.apply` is necessary remove first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df[['num_col1_SMA', 'num_col2_SMA']] = (things_groupby[['num_col1','num_col2']]
                                               .rolling(window=N)
                                               .mean()
                                               .droplevel(0))
```